# db.schema() didn't show correctly after bulk import through neo4j admin

Tags: neo4j

Hi I download our db to csv, then import the data to neo4jDB through bulk import method: neo4j-admin import. It works, and data can be seen in neo4j browser. but we I typed 'call db.schema()', the schema is wrong.[image: schema error]

this is the relative table:
[image]

it seems event Node became relationships in this query.
then I tried to call "call db.schema.nodeTypeProperties()" and "call db.schema.relTypeProperties()", it looks good, like this:
[image]

Also, if i tried to do some queries and expand relationships in neo4j browser it works.

So any body have any idea what happened? or any hints to debug this??

Answer (score 2):

The `db.schema()` procedure and its successor `db.schema.visualization()` have their limitations (that look like bugs). The issue exists since about v3.0 and does not seem to be fixed anytime soon.
Instead, you can use `apoc.meta.graph()` procedure from the APOC library. It works properly but not so fast.

Please see [this](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/) to install APOC using Neo4j Desktop. If you're using standalone Community Edition, you need to:

1. Download APOC .jar file (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases)
2. Copy it to the `plugins` directory inside your Neo4j installation. On Windows, unblock the file.
3. In the `neo4j.conf` file, enable loading APOC functions by inserting this line:
       `dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*`
4. Restart the server.

Comment: I used call ```apoc.meta.graph()```, still similar error. I think maybe there are some error in my data structure? should I define schema manually before or after loading data?